# numpy array of array with custom filtering

Tags: numpy

I am trying to filter a numpy array of array with given conditions, for example

```
input = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[0,9,19]])

output where the [0] >= 4, [1] >= 5, [2] >= 6

expected result = np.array([[4,5,6],[4,5,6]])
```

what would be the best way to achieve this with performance concern?

extended question: and how to retrieve the correspondance index of the each output elements in the input array?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```py
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[0,9,19]])
a[(a[:,0] >=4) & (a[:,1] >= 5) & (a[:,2] >=6)]
```

Here you create binary masks for the conditions on each elements in each row of the data, use the *logical and* to combine them, and finally use the resulting mask to get the matching data rows.

To find the index of the data rows matching the conditions, you can use numpys `where()` function:

```py
idx = np.where((a[:,0] >=4) & (a[:,1] >= 1) & (a[:,2] >=6))[0]
```

Comment: How about getting the correspondence index??

Comment: I added it to the answer

Answer (score 1):

As per your request, a numba version

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import sys
import timeit

target = np.random.randint(low=-100000, high=100000, size=(int(sys.argv[2]), 3), dtype=np.int)
comp = np.array([4, 5, 6])

@nb.njit((nb.int64[:, :], nb.int64[::3]), parallel=True)
def cmp(a, b):
    c = np.empty((a.shape[0],), dtype=a.dtype)
    for i in nb.prange(a.shape[0]):
        c[i] = a[i][0] > b[0] and a[i][1] > b[1] and a[i][2] > b[2]
    return c


def cmp_normal(a, b):
    # return np.all(a > b, axis=1)
    return (a[:,0] >=b[0]) & (a[:,1] >= b[1]) & (a[:,2] >=b[2])


print(timeit.timeit(lambda: eval(sys.argv[1])(target, comp), number=10))
```

First output time is for sequential numba, second one is for parallel numba.
Parallel numba gives 5 times speed up compared to sequential

```sh
(base) xxx@xxx:~$ python test.py cmp 1000000
6.40756068899982
(base) xxx@xxx:~$ python test.py cmp 1000000
1.3425709140001345
```

Now vanilla numpy

```sh
(base) xxx@xxx:~$ python test.py cmp_normal 1000000
4.04174472700015
```

Numba parallel is fastest. But if you try to return a[c] instead, numba will slow down. So it depends on what you write

Comment: No matching definition for argument type(s) array(int32, 2d, C), array(int32, 1d, C)

Comment: error means by default np.int32 is used. try replacing all the places with np.int32 instead of np.int and np.int64

Comment: How would I be possible to retreieve the index of the result as in the original input??  

In fact, I am having another array which is storing the strings (representing as the keys to those values in the format of [int, int, int].

Comment: My target it to get the key : value pairs after the filtering.

Comment: Onces you get c, then np.argwhere(c) is the key/index and a[c] is the value at those index

Comment: Also other answer should be suitable for your purpose if speed is not bottleneck. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers , Which ever you choose, don't forget to accept most helpful answer

Comment: Thanks you.. The a[c] is essential for me. The original data structure was a key value pair as in format like {str : [int, int, int], str : [int, int, int]}. so the keys are important as indicator.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [223]: arr =np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[0,9,19]])
In [224]: arr
Out[224]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 0,  9, 19]])
```

Since you are testing values, one for each column, you can do a simple `numpy` `==` test  (the (3,) test `broadcasts` with the (4,3) arr)

```
In [225]: arr==[4,5,6]
Out[225]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False]])
```

and where a whole row  is true:

```
In [226]: (arr==[4,5,6]).all(axis=1)
Out[226]: array([False,  True,  True, False])
```

This can be applied as a boolean mask to select those rows from `arr`:

```
In [227]: arr[_]
Out[227]: 
array([[4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

and the numeric indices:

```
In [228]: np.nonzero(__)
Out[228]: (array([1, 2]),)
```